# Spring multiple PersistenceContexts

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa-2.0

There are many variations on the setup of multiple persistence contexts within spring, but none that explain the problem that I am facing.

I have an application context structure like this:

```
core AC
`-- web-root AC
```

In my core application context i have defined both my two datasources and a transactionManager as well as a single EntityManagerFactory bean:

```
<!-- core applicationContext.xml -->
<beans ...>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    ...
    <!-- Container managed datasources -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="module1DS" jndi-name="jdbc/module1DS" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="securityDS" jndi-name="jdbc/securityDS" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager"/>

    <bean id="securityEMF" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="securityPU"/>
        <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="securityDS"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.security.model"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.websphere.WebSphereLoadTimeWeaver"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

In the web-root application context i have defined an additional EMF:

```
<!-- module1 applicationContext.xml -->
<beans...>
    ....
    <bean id="module1EMF" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="module1PU"/>
        <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="module1DS"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.module1.model"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.OpenJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.websphere.WebSphereLoadTimeWeaver"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Now I have a couple entities defined under the `com.example.core.model` package in the core module and also a single entity defined in the `com.example.module1.model` package in module1 (which is a war in an ear).

There is a service defined in core that gets the EntityManager injected into with the securityPU PersistenceContext and performs a named query on an entity in the database:

```
@Service("coreThingService")
public class CoreEntityThingServiceImpl implements CoreEntityThingService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "securityPU")
    @Qualifier("securityEMF")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<CoreEntityThing> getCoreEntityThingById(String id) {
        // select a from CoreEntityThing a where a.id = :id
        TypedQuery<CoreEntityThing> query = em.createNamedQuery("CoreEntityThing.findById", CoreEntityThing.class);
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

nevermind about my unusual logic here, the point is that when this service is injected into the web-tier inside a `@Controller` and invoked, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: An error occurred while parsing the 
>query filter "select a from CoreEntityThing a where a.id = :id". Error message: The 
>name "CoreEntityThing" is not a recognized entity or identifier. Perhaps you meant 
>Module1Entity, which is a close match. Known entity names: [Module1Entity]
```

I have Inspected the injected em:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "securityPU")
@Qualifier("securityEMF")
private EntityManager em;
```

and have found it to be the securityPU as expected, what i didn't expect however is when it said that it couldn't find the entities (even though the `packagesToScan` property of the `securityEMF` was correctly pointing to the right package).

More strangely, it suggested an entity in the 'child' PU -- `Module1Entity` -- that should not have been picked up in the securityEMF.

What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1:** I have updated my application context xml descriptions to make clear how i have created my PUs

**UPDATE 2:** It appears my classes are being scanned as I can see them in the persistence unit at runtime, what is really intriguing, is that up until the invokation of the `createNamedQuery` method on the EntityManager proxy is called (using `method.invoke(targetPU, name)` where `method` is the createNamedQuery function and `targetPU` is the `securityEMF` PU), The PU remains as the securityEMF. I can't go any deeper into code to see what createNamedQuery is actually doing, but during this invokation, the described error is thrown! what on earth is happening?!

To make things clearer, The error message's query string:

```
"select a from CoreEntityThing a where a.id = :id"
```

sits on top of my CoreEntityThing class!

```
package com.example.core.model.security;
...

@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "CoreEntityThing.findById", query = "select ...")
public class CoreEntityThing { ... }
```

so it is finding the entity, then claiming it knows nothing about it!

**UPDATE 3:** I've read in [this blog post](http://labs.bsb.com/2010/11/configuring-modular-jpa-applications-with-spring/) about a supposed limitation of JPA PersistenceUnits having limited modularity. can anyone point me to more documentation about this limitation and any examples of multi module enterprise solutions using multiple datasources. This has to be a common concern for a large number of sizable projects.

Comment: I've seen similar case where the cause was mistake between `@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier` and `@javax.inject.Qualifier`. To be honest I don't know which one should be applied, but you might want to swap it just to try

Comment: The javax.inject.Qualifier doesn't have a 'name' variable to set. I am using the `org.spring...Qualifier`, The Qualifier annotation does not matter much as i get the same persistence unit regardless

Comment: Do you have any `packagesToScan` inside `securityPU`?

Comment: yes, I've included it in the question.

Comment: I only see persistence.xml for `module1PU`, not for `securityPU`

Comment: using spring, you don't explicitly need a persistence.xml, the two configuration files you see there are both spring xml configuration files. you can opt in for spring's component-scan mechanism to scan for entities, or so I've been told.

Comment: I know that you don't need to `persistence.xml` for Spring 3.1+, but you have mixed both methods. That is why I am asking. My point is that you might have specified `packagesToScan` in both Spring configuration and `persistence.xml`

Comment: My apologies, I must not have made my self clear in the question, please see the revised version and tell me if you understand what i have done now.

Comment: Ok, so to make it clear, you are not using `persistence.xml`, but you have set `persistenceUnitName` (in order to give it a name maybe) in your EMF Spring configuration? If that is the case, you should drop `persistenceUnitName` from the Spring configuration and just use the `id` of the bean as a unitName for `@PersistenceContext`

Comment: That's correct, unfortunately I have done what you suggested and the same error occurs :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55810/discussion-between-thenaglecode-and-geoand).